# Is using H.264 in Chromium allowed?

Tags: chromium

Chromium enables us to build it with support of H.264 and even H.265.

I would like to ask if any license fees have to be paid for that or how the licenses are being handled.

Thank you.

Comment: Chromium doesn't provide non-free codecs by default. If you have a license for h264+aac you can enable those codecs with ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" and proprietary_codecs=true source: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/Qh49e3wcyKM/wlGMytSCBQAJ That is an official Chromium dev group used by Chromium developers